# Include quotes around json aws sns call

Tags: c#, json, google-api, aws-sdk

I need for AWS SNS the correct formatted JSON object but my format is wrong.

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.GCM = new ExpandoObject {};
foo.GCM.data = new ExpandoObject();
foo.GCM.data.message = "bogus";
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

The result:
{"GCM":{"data":{"message":"bogus"}}}

Required format: {"GCM":"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"bogus\"}}"}

Answer (score 1):

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.data = new ExpandoObject();
foo.data.message = "bogus";
string json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { GCM=json1 } , Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

**OUTPUT:** `{"GCM":"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"bogus\"}}"}`

But I don't understand why this *Required format* needs double serialization. Are you sure about it?

Comment: "Thank You". They have multiple payload formats in SNS.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-custommessage.html

Comment: Yep. AWS SNS needs a stringified version of a json dictionary object.